# Ruby on Rails : How to implement simple user Management in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have developed a Rails 4 application and I am planning to use a simple and efficient user management solution in my application. I have checked the `Devise gem` and found that it has a lot of features which i don't want to implement/mess with in my code.

My User management is very simple:  I have a list of users. Each user has some role intern bring to some privileges. I want to store the currently logged in user some where in application which can be accessed anywhere from within the application. I also want to check in the controller whether the current logged in user has access to this controller.

I am not authenticating the user against my local Database, instead I am doing that using Facebook.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=authentication

Answer (score 5):

Check out [sorcery](https://rubygems.org/gems/sorcery), it's more lightweight and less obscure than Devise. This is its philosophy (extracted from [readme](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/README.md)):

> Sorcery is a stripped-down, bare-bones authentication library, with
>   which you can write your own authentication flow. It was built with a
>   few goals in mind:
>
> - Less is more - less than 20 public methods to remember for the entire
>     feature-set make the lib easy to 'get'.
> - No built-in or generated code - use the library's methods inside *your
>     own* MVC structures, and don't fight to fix someone else's.
> - Magic yes, Voodoo no - the lib should be easy to hack for most developers.
> - Configuration over Confusion - Centralized (1 file), Simple & short
>     configuration as possible, not drowning in syntactic sugar.
> - Keep MVC cleanly separated - DB is for models, sessions are for
>     controllers. Models stay unaware of sessions.

[Here](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/External) you can read about using sorcery together with Facebook authentication.